# How I can add a line break before the numbers?

Tags: php

I would like to add a line break between the bolded content.

This is what is being displayed in a column

85025 Blood Count Complete Auto&auto Difrntl Wbc **Count82977** Glutamyltrase Gamma80053 Comprehensive Metabolic **Panel81000** Urinls Dip Stick/tablet Reagnt Non-auto Micrscpy

I have changed it to `<br>` and it does not work

```
 $subject = ucwords(strtolower($row['myitem']));

echo "  <td class='detail'>&nbsp;" . $subject . "</td>\n";
```

Comment: also what is the content of `$subject` ?

Comment: A visual linebreak when rendering in the browser or in your resulting HTML..?

Comment: subject is each item coming from a MySQL query.

Comment: Coming from MySql does not answer what it is. We can make an assumption that it is some sort of string... but does it have structure because it makes a difference to how we can help you.

Comment: sorry, so it is a whole string....what is there is a string from array...I would like to be able to add a line break on that string stored in the array.

Answer (score 0):

here `$row` is array with multiple`myitem` yes? so `$subject` is an array 
so you ve to loop through each value of array `$subject`

```
foreach($subject as $key=>$value){
     echo '<tr><td class="detail">&nbsp;' . $value . '</td></tr>';
}
```

here `<tr>` gives you line break.

If i've understand you properly may be it's you are looking for or let me know if i am wrong..

Comment: so it 'myitem' is the array that contains the whole string shown. So this will work if there are separate myitem. But, my item is the final string. Do not know how many can be, that is should be number plus description and new line before next number and description

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
<?php
$subject = "85025 Blood Count Complete Auto&auto Difrntl Wbc Count82977 Glutamyltrase Gamma80053 Comprehensive Metabolic Panel81000 Urinls Dip Stick/tablet Reagnt Non-auto Micrscpy";

$searchStr1 = "Count82977";
$searchStr2 = "Panel81000";

$str1 = str_replace($searchStr1, '<br/>'.$searchStr1.'<br/>', $subject);

$str2 = str_replace($searchStr2, '<br/>'.$searchStr2.'<br/>', $str1);

echo $str2;
?>
```

Comment: The problem is that there is no problem if there is only one description, i.e. number and description. It can be many so to make it $searchStr1, $searchStr2....there can be many